# Reading python shell line from VB6

Tags: python, vb6

I have python script that prints as result a file path.
I need to read convert that result into a string that can be used as a variable in my vb6 program.[This is the output of the script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LJshu.png)

I tried different code that i found on web but none of them worked.
I post them anyway since it can be my mistake.

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()

 Dim wscript As Object
 Dim objShell As Object
 Dim objExecObject As Object

   Set objShell = wscript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
   Set objExecObject = objShell.Exec("python.exe /k Get_Info.py")
   Text1.Text = ""
   Do While Not objExecObject.StdOut.AtEndOfStream
        Text1.Text = Text1.Text & vbCrLf & objExecObject.StdOut.ReadLine()
   Loop
End Sub
```

With this one I don't know very well how to declare the 3 variables so i'm not sure isn't working

```
Private Sub Command4_Click()

  Shell "python.exe Get_Info.py folder", vbMaximizedFocus
  Sleep 1000
  MsgBox Command$
End Sub
```

This one instead doesnt' get anything. Returns Command$ as ""
I also tried typing

```
script = App.path & "\" & "Get_Info.py"

path = Shell("python.exe script & parameter ", vbMaximizedFocus)

Sleep 1000

MsgBox path
```

I get a different 4 digit number as output everytime i click but no trace of the path.

Please help me on this :) 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

Set wmic = WshShell.Exec("cmd /c echo hello")
Do While wmic.Status = 0
    WScript.Sleep 100
Loop

Decoded = Replace(wmic.StdOut.ReadAll, vbcrlf, "")
```

Note I use ReadAll rather than looping. This is VBScript which can be pasted into VB6. You can in VB6 use early binding and `Dim` your objects as `Dim x As WshShell`
 after adding a Reference (Project Menu) to *Windows Script Host Object Model* which is far faster method calls (although you won't notice if doing it once).

Python can also use COM objects.

**Update**

As you are aware by using `app.path` you can't guarantee system configuration, and nor should you change the users environment - except to make your program available (ie Start menu).

VB6 prorams, except for simple programs, need to be installed on computers. Just because it works on a computer with the VB6 development environment doesn't mean it will work elsewhere without installing. Use the Package and Deployment Wizard on the Addin menu.

However the application directory (ie `app.path`) is only writable by administrators. Programs use AppData directory for files they need to create, write, or read but are not for the user to open.

User's data go into Documents, Pictures, Video, Etc.

To get these folders you use (there's a lot of functions from different era's of Windows) one of them like https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/0ea7b5xe(v=vs.84).aspx.

For the era of software that you are using see Windows 2000 Guide I picked the best three chapters of *Application Specification for Microsoft Windows 2000 for Desktop Applications Design Guide for Building Business Applications* https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms954115.aspx‎

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms954375.aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb742580.aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms954371.aspx

Comment: i'm trying using your code but comes out that I need to declare 'WScript'. How should I do it? I mean what type of variable is it? Also do i need to do the same with 'wmic' ? Sorry but has been a long time since i stop using VB so I forgot a lot of things :)

Comment: I've just declared them as "Dim WScript" without saying the type but now it says Object required...

Comment: You have to add a reference. after adding a Reference (Project Menu) to Windows Script Host Object Model. OR don't change it at all.

Comment: the error seems to be in                                                                                  " Set WshShell = Wscript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")"

Comment: `Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")` Ops I was using WSH's `CreateObject` rather than VB's `CreateObject`.

Comment: ok removing WScript it works! :) do you know why after it opens the cmd it minimize the program and shows me the code instead of the form?

Comment: Do you mean the batchfile you see. Then that's a consequence of using the exec object. You can use `whshell.run program.bat, 0, true` (hidden window) but then you lose access to StdOut and would have to redirect to a file and load the file.

Comment: i prefer not to use a file. anyway since i need to run a python script, i tried `(path = App.path & "\Take_Photo.py"` 
   `Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")` 
  `Set wmic = WshShell.Exec("python \c path")`

Comment: You have to give it a valid python command line. Normally something like `"python ""c:\folder\take_photo.py"""`.

Comment: it works. now i need to figure out how to get the output cause it only return {}. if i use the same commands typing them manually it return like image i posted. if i put the command into a py file it doesn't display it. i don't know why

Comment: You probably need to give it a filename to open or something.

Comment: what do you mean? basically when i use this command the gopro takes a photo and python displays the path of it which is an URL (like the photo i put). If I write manually all the commands on the shell it display the path as last line, but if i run a script.py with the same commands it takes the photo but it doesn't display the path!

Comment: Start a new question about the python part. I'm a basic programmer and don't use python.

Comment: i'll do it. Thanks for your help!!! i have one last question. do you know if is possible to use the app.path instead of typing the complete path? because i will need it to run the program on another PC and for sure the folder is going to be different

Comment: Yes you can. It's good practise to use all the information functions (ie where is MyDocs located - `wshshell.SpecialFolders(objWshSpecialFolders)` 
) to make your program configuration independent. But you are always advised to use Package and Deployment Wizard (on Add In menu in VB6) so any VB controls get registered on the target computer.

Comment: do you mind if I open a post about it so you can explane me that better? I just need to figure out how to open a post :)

Comment: I can edit my answer. You can edit your question. Be specific on what you want to know.

Comment: sorry but i'm new on this "forum" so i don't know very well how it works. anyway I told you i would like to use the app.path since i will run it on other PC. Then if you can tell me something about making the program configuration indipendent. what does it mean?

Comment: is the first time i try to make a program to be installed and run on other pc so I don't really know what to do

Comment: I edit my answer in a while. But using App.Path is one part of making your app configuration independent.

Comment: @david  I've Updated

Comment: Thanks @ACatInLove i'll take a look at the links you post